# Managing concurrency on store checkout process

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, locking

I have been reading all day searching the correct way to manage concurrency within a e-commerce checkout process, and I'm still not sure how to develop it.

**Scenario**

User selects *one* product from the store, go to checkout page and pays using his credit card. The site process the payment checking **stock availability** and using a webservice along with the user credit card data and. The webservice finally return the result and the site display a success page (or fail).

**Final checkout  and payment validation flow**

- The user starts the final checkout step
- I check if product has stock
- If product has stock I call the payment webservice
- If webservice result is "OK", I display the success page

It sounds very simple, but my problem is the way I get the stock of the product: I have to calculate it each time. I have two tables *product* and *sales* (example only tables), so each time a sale is completed, a *sale row* is added linking the product it belongs. On *product* table I have the maximum times that a product can be sold, like a initial stock.

So, for example, I have product **X** with initial stock of 99 and two users starts the checkout process for the last available unit. I check the current sold units = 98. OK, both users can buy it, I call the webservice and finally both users buy and pay the product.

Any idea of how to deal with concurrency in this case?

BTW: I'm usingy MySQL with InnodB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally implemented **Optimistic Offline Lock** (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html) pattern, so only one user at time can purchase an item. I had to be very careful managin dead user connections with timeouts if a user abandon the transaction.